# Someone who speaks very little but uses precise and direct words in short sentences

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the adjective to describe a person that speaks very little, but when he/she does, his / her sentences are kept to a minimal length and words are sharp, precise and powerful. Think of those "Clint Eastwood" type of movie character that use one-liners and use as few words as possible to get their point across.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjective meaning "not speaking much"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236911/adjective-meaning-not-speaking-much) ... also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177943/a-word-that-means-of-few-words-or-without-words/177945#177945), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222058/a-word-for-not-wanting-to-talk-much/222069#222069) and many others [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-request%5D+laconic)

Answer (score 3):

You most probably refer to the adjective ***laconic***:

> Brief, concise, and to the point ([Source -Wordhippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/laconic.html))

You will find many synonyms on this site.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laconic) defines it as

> using few words; expressing much in few words; concise.

Comment: I see you got DVed...not mine. I assume the DVer is objecting to answering a Q which has a clear dupe.

Comment: Since the comments have been locked, it is almost impossible to tell the OP that the SWR tag requires a sample sentence, or that research is needed to avoid dupe, etc. It puts the onus on the answerer to make that determination.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The DV probably meant I haven't done my homework to check if the question was a duplicate or not. But because the question was closed temporarily and not as a duplicate was a dupe in itself. I am not saying it was voluntary, I simply assumed it was not a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have become a casualty of the continuing 'war' over answering in comment v. answering an un-researched Q.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess the intentions are all good in the end.

Comment: Perhaps this should be raised on Meta. People can up/downvote whatever they like, for whatever *reason* they like. But I'm sure the vast majority of users (and I'd assume *all* mods on *all* SO sites) would agree that "Because there's an obvious pre-existing duplicate of this question" is definitely NOT a defensible closevote reason.

Comment: I always thought that, but bore with it. Thank you for the suggestion, I think I will raise it on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster defines **succinct** as—

> marked by compact precise expression without wasted words

*a succinct description*

There's a word with the same meaning and Vocabulary.com uses the exact same word to describe the economical-with-words nature of Clint Eastwood (that is, they exemplify the word by citing Eastwood as example; I can't unfortunately recall the word.)

Answer (score -1):

"**Lapidary**" is an adjective that combines the ideas of conciseness, elegance and exactness.

- ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lapidary?q=lapidary)) (formal) (especially of written language) exact and showing good style
  SYNONYM concise
- (SOED) dignified, concise